# How to tune group by query in Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark job which uses the following group by query. I know group by is evil but I can't avoid it in my use case. I tried to use it both using `DataFrame` and `hiveContext.sql()` but both shuffles huge data and is very slow: one query takes around 5 minutes. I have seen one group by stage does shuffle read of 20 GB and shuffle write of 10 GB. I have around 8 fields passed in as group by fields

```
sourceFrame.select("blabla").groupby("col1","col2","col3",..."col8").agg("bla bla");
```

OR

```
hiveContext.sql("insert into table partitions bla bla group by "col1","col2","col3",..."col8"");
```

I have tried almost all tuning parameters like tungsten,lz4, more `spark.shuffle.memoryFraction` around 0.6. Most of the time group by stage in Spark UI waits for shuffle read and hangs there for even hours. I am using Spark 1.4.0.

Comment: did you try reducebykey?

Comment: Have you tried setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` higher? It defaults to 200 but having more partitions should help move less data at a time.

Answer (score 1):

reduceByKey is alternative option of groupBy but you need to convert from dataframe to RDD. I had similar kind of issue but i solved using df.rdd and then use reduceByKey

Comment: We can't use reduceBykey on multiple keys like I mentioned I have 8 keys on which I do group by